How can I output a list of objects in a CloudFormation template?
I've got a template for an ECS service which I am using for multiple different microservices. I need to start passing different secrets to some of the services. I'm trying to pass in a comma separated list of key-value pairs:
Parameters:
  Secrets:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Description: A comma delimited list of SSM parameters to expose as environment variables e.g. CONNECTION_STRING=/limbus/connectionString,API_KEY=/limbus/apiKey
    Default: ''

I need this to be translated to the following structure:
Secrets:
  - Name: CONNECTION_STRING
    ValueFrom: /limbus/connectionString
  - Name: API_KEY
    ValueFrom: /limbus/apiKey

What I've tried so far:
Secrets:
  Fn::ForEach::Secret:
    - KeyValuePair
    - !Ref Secrets
    - Name: !Select [0, !Split ['=', !Sub '${KeyValuePair}']]
      ValueFrom: !Select [1, !Split ['=', !Sub '${KeyValuePair}']]

This is close but it's outputting an object instead of a list. With one secret, I get an object as the output and the deployment fails:

Model validation failed (#/ContainerDefinitions/0/Secrets: expected type: JSONArray, found: JSONObject)

"Secrets": {
  "Name": "ApiKey",
  "ValueFrom": "/limbus/apiKey"
},

With two secrets, I get an error while applying the ForEach loop:

Duplicate key 'Name' when merging keys to parent object in Fn::ForEach

Is there a way to append to a list instead of defining named objects?
